# Debug Jest with Electron using VS Code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, jestjs, electron, vscode-debugger

I can't manage to debug my Jest tests in VS Code when I use Electron. My tests should run with Electron, not with Node (due to the use of native modules).

```
{
  "name": "Jest Unit Tests",
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
  "windows": {
    "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
  },
  "env": {
    "ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE": "1",
    "NODE_ENV": "test",
    "BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE": "1"
  },
  "args": [
    "-i",
    "--verbose",
    "-c test/config/jest.unit.json"
  ],
  "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
},
```

It is based on the usual config used to debug Jest with Node (which works fine), but I can't get it to work with Electron. The Jest command is correct, but the `--debug-brk --inspect` option added by VSCode seems to mess out with Jest.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Running into the same issue myself

Comment: No sorry I did not use the debugger with this project. Debugging with Node is usually sufficient though, except for specific Electron code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my config to work based on your question. Thanks!

```json
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Debug Current Jest File:Electron",
  "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
  "args": [
    "--verbose",
    "-i",
    "--no-cache",
    "--testPathPattern",
    "${fileBasename}",
    "--coverage",
    "false"
  ],
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
  "env": {
    "ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE": "true"
  }
}
```